# LPAD without trimming in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to add 0 at the beginning of an ID without trimming it :

I am currently using `LPAD(id,4,"0")` witch works fine until `9999`

- Request : `SELECT LPAD(12345,4,"0");`
- Excepted result : `12345`
- Result : `1234`

I am Looking for a Request who does `LPAD(id, MAX(LENGTH(id),4), "0")`

I found `SELECT IF(LENGTH(12345)>4, 12345, LPAD(12345, 4, "0"));` but i would prefer if the `4` was in a single place (to make it easier use it elsewhere).

- Is there a build-in function that does what i'm looking For ?
- Or is there an alternative to the function `MAX()` that would work in that situation ?
- Or should I stick with the `IF(LENGTH)` solution and it's drawbacks ?

**Edit :**

`ZEROFILL` doesn't fit my needs because I also need the id without `0`s.
I mainly use the ID without the `LPAD()`, but when I do, I use it with a prefix : `CONCAT("PFX", LPAD(id,4,"0"))`

**Thanks for your Help**

*PS: please tell me if i do anything wrong, it's my first time asking here.*

Comment: Question is fine, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I had similar problem with LPAD, it was truncating number to its pad length. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad it is expected result.

As far as I can see, nobody mentioned answer that solved my same problem:

```sql
LPAD(id, GREATEST(LENGTH(id), 4), "0")
```

It works as expected. Pads any `id`'s shorter than 4 characters with 0, and returns unchanged `id`'s that are longer than 4 characters.

I'm leaving my answer here for other people, that will find this question in the future.

Comment: That's what i've ended up doing, as advised at the end of the accepted answer

Comment: I don't see any answer with solution provided by me. Everyone else is using some mix of `SUBSTRING`'s, `CONCAT`'s or `REGEXP_REPLACE`'s. I posted this answer, so anyone else that finds this question (as I did) will be provided few possibilities :)

Comment: My bad, I misread Daniel's answer, your answer was what i was looking for back then

Answer (score 2):

You can cat the length of a int field and also set zerofill like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `num` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Numbers` int(5) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Insert values:

```
INSERT INTO `num` (`id`, `Numbers`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 22),
    (3, 123456);
```

See the result:

```
MariaDB []> select * from num;
+----+---------+
| id | Numbers |
+----+---------+
|  1 |   00001 |
|  2 |   00022 |
|  3 |  123456 |
+----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

without zerofill you can calc it like:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  SUBSTRING( CONCAT('000000',Numbers),- GREATEST(LENGTH(Numbers),5))
FROM num;
```

Result:

```
MariaDB []>     SELECT
    ->       id,
    ->       SUBSTRING( CONCAT('000000',Numbers),- GREATEST(LENGTH(Numbers),5))
    ->     FROM num;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | SUBSTRING( CONCAT('000000',Numbers),- GREATEST(LENGTH(Numbers),5)) |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 00001                                                              |
|  2 | 00022                                                              |
|  3 | 123456                                                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `ZEROFILL` doesn't fit my needs because I also need the id without `0`s elsewhere. (I've just updated my question).

Comment: @Pierre Lezan - i have change my answer

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, why a number would need leading zeroes at all. No number in practical and theoretical math needs leading zeroes.

Maybe you want to visuals something, and not work with the result as a real number.
In that case, you can either declare the field in the table `ZEROFILL` and select it converted to char: `SELECT CONVERT(id, CHAR);`.

Other than that, the only way is a mix of `CONCAT()` and `LENGTH()`, that way you avoid stripping the ID to the value in `LPAD()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `ZEROFILL` doesn't fit my needs because I also need the id without `0`s.  The main use case is with a prefix : `COM0123`.   I don't fully understand how to use `CONCAT()` with a variable amount of `0`

Comment: @PierreLezan I think you should first understand the difference between a number / integer and a string / char. There is **no** semantical / mathematical difference between `000012` and `12` and either does not affect integrity when used as a number.

Answer (score 0):

### LPAD

You can achieve this with an `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do a `LPAD` equivalent but without truncating the result. If you want a minimum length of 4 and padding with 0, you can do:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT('0000', id), '^0{0,4}(.{4,})$', '\\1')
```

You can adapt this by replacing `'0000'` with `REPEAT('0', 4)` to do it programmatically. The main advantage in this approach, is to not repeating the padded thing. In my use cases, I can have very long and complex things that I don't want to duplicate to only pad them, so this code fragment do its job.

### RPAD

For those who have the problem for `RPAD`, you need a very close pattern:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(id, '0000'), '^(.{4,}?)0{0,4}$', '\\1')
```

The two blocks in the pattern are essentially inverted but you can see `.{4,}?` instead of `.{4,}`. It's for set the greediness to lazy for the `{4,}` quantifier. It's needed here.